# Creating a code to perform hundreds of google searches and extract publication date

Tags: python, google-search

Using python, how can I create a script to performing hundreds of google searches to gather the publication dates of the first link.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this is not a code-writing or tutorial site, and we ask that questions be specific and include a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is create a spider. Scrapy is one way to do them on python. You tell it how to go to next page and what you want to scrape etc. and it does it for you. You can research more from it's git repo https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy

But be aware that Google doesn't really want people scraping and have deployed some counter measures.

Here is some information on search engine scraping
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_scraping